# React Native Make PDF file

Tags: react-native, pdf

I want to make a pdf file into android phone. So far i just found https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-html-to-pdf allow me to make a pdf file but it used html. Is there any others packages other than **react-native-html-to-pdf** able to make a pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

> Yes,there is: react-native-pdf-lib
>
> > here is the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf-lib